# Переопределение стилей при адаптивной вёрстке

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой при адаптивной вёрстке - не применяются новые стили при определённом разрешении экрана. Например в десктопе h1 имеет font-size = 60px, а при определённом разрешении, допустим, 768px, не воспринимает h1  font-size = 30px, только если применить !important.
Почему так происходит и можно ли без !important это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема найдена - это порядок следования. Медиа-запросы нужно устанавливать после обычных стилей.